# Print subclasses of all defined classes without printing the unsatisfied classes

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

i am new to OWLAPi , i am using Jfact1.2.1 reasoner.

In my ontology there are two unsatisfiable classes . I want to print all the subclasses without these two unsatisfied classes. I've made some codes using array and i was successful however, i didn't like this array thing as i can not use it for other unknown ontologies which might have more than 2 unsatisfiable classes.

So my question is, is there a way to print out all the subclasses of defined classes without having the unsitisfiable classes present in them? 
i really need someone's help as i've tried everything. 
If anyone is interested in the array method i've used to the codes are below

```
OWLClass[] array = new OWLClass[3];
int i=0;

Node<OWLClass> bottomNode = reasoner.getUnsatisfiableClasses();

    Set<OWLClass> unsatisfiable = bottomNode.getEntitiesMinusBottom();


        for (OWLClass cls : unsatisfiable) {


            array[i]= cls;
            i++;
        }
    for (OWLClass c : myOntology.getClassesInSignature()) {
NodeSet<OWLClass> subClasses = reasoner.getSubClasses(c, True);

        for (OWLClass subClass : subClasses.getFlattened()) {
if (subClass.isBottomEntity()|| subClass.equals(array[0])|| 
     subClass.equals(array[1])|| subClass.equals(array[2])){


      continue;

else{
    System.out.println(subClass.getIRI().getFragment() + "\tsubclass of\t" 
   + c.getIRI().getFragment());
 }
}
}
```

Comment: What is an unsatisfied class?

Comment: These are classes which are equivalent to owl:Nothing. Also, they appear to be the subclass pf every defined class.

Comment: yeah. lol. I feel stupid now

Comment: Aside from your main question, if you're new to OWLAPI I'd recommend to use OWLAPI 4.0.1 and JFact 4.0.0, unless you have a reason to use older versions.

Comment: yes, reason is Professor told me to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if (subClass.isBottomEntity()|| subClass.equals(array[0])|| 
 subClass.equals(array[1])|| subClass.equals(array[2])){
```

with

```
if (subClass.isBottomEntity()|| unsatisfiable.contains(subclass)) {
```

which has the same effect.  There's no need for you to copy the `unsatisfiable` set out to an array.

Comment: OMG, how did u do that? Bro, i've spent last 2 hours thinking about this. U r really good .

Comment: This code is correct, but it can be made one better:
'Set<OWLClass> unsatisfiable = bottomNode.getEntities();`
`if(unsatisfiable.contains(subClass)){ // then skip it because it is owl:Nothing or an unsatisfiable class}`